# Total Tweets Count Computation for a Trend

Tags: twitter, trend

How can I compute the total volume of unique tweets for a trend on Twitter, considering that the tweet volume can both increase and decrease over time? Let's take the example of a trend called #ABC that trended for 5 hours, with the following tweet volumes:

Hour 1: 100 tweets
Hour 2: 200 tweets
Hour 3: 300 tweets
Hour 4: 230 tweets
Hour 5: 270 tweets

In this example, we can see that the tweet volume increased initially but then decreased. The total volume cannot be obtained by a simple sum because each hour's tweet volume includes the tweets from the previous hour. Additionally, the tweet volume does not always increase; it can also decrease.

So, how can I compute the total count of unique tweets considering these factors?